# XmlDeserialization after renaming the classes involved

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I have a bunch of xml serialized objects in a database.

But, I refactored and renamed the classes involved, so deserializing from the db is difficult.

I thought that by adding the term `[XmlRoot("DB_Class_Name")]` atop the renamed classes would fix the issue, but it doesn't appear to.

Is there a way to fix the issue using labels like `[XmlRoot]`, `[XmlElement]` etc., without renaming my classes to their old classnames, and without writing a special deserialize function?

Also, are there any good sources on what is happening under the hood when using xmldeserializaiton and labels like `[XmlRoot]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `[XmlRoot]` etc. aren't labels, they're attributes.

Second, `[XmlRoot]` only affects the class when that class is used as the root element of the document. It has no affect when an instance of that class is used as a child or other descendant.

Use `[XmlType]` on the class, or `[XmlElement]` on a property that is of the type of the class.